# Having trouble writing comments today

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Hey I noticed this morning every time I click on the "Add comment" text my browser pops back up to the top of the question rather than opening up a comment text box.

Is there something wrong with my browser or is there a glitch in the html code?

Edit: I'm on Windows Explorer 8, OS is Windows 7. I'm seeing the same problem on other Stack Exchange sites as well.

I've enabled java applet scripting via Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level... then closed & reopened my browser, still no luck.

@phantom42 - Thanks - active scripting is enabled, and used the checker and looks like javascript is enabled. Hmm, weird.

Comment: What browser version and OS? Does it happen on other sites?

Comment: I was able to recreate this effect by disabling javascript in FF/XP

Comment: Is your Javascript disabled?

Comment: Java Applet scripting is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: In IE8, you should be looking for Scripting -> Active Scripting.

Comment: You can check real quickly to see if javascript is enabled using a checker like [this](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/is-javascript-enabled).

Comment: I just recreated this bug in IE8/WinXP with javascript enabled. There's a javascript error in full.en.js

Comment: @phantom42 - what's the error? I don't have IE 8 on this machine, so any detail would help.

Comment: @Oded, unfortunately, it doesn't provide anything useful. It just says script error in line 0, char 0 of full.en.js code 0, uri: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=d517eed677bf

Comment: @phantom42 - sigh. Looks like the browser chokes on _something_ there. Did you apply MS patches today on your IE8/WinXP?

Comment: @Oded No. I think there may have been a patch last week, but nothing today.

Comment: I have tried IE 8 on a Windows 7 VM - could not reproduce this issue at all. What extensions are you using? Any ad-blockers?

Comment: @Oded, nope. Standard government issued (literally) IE8. Specifically version 8.0.6001.18702. There may be a security policy in place that I can't access though, as I'm not allowed to change my security level in IE.

Comment: @phantom42 - ok. I am wondering if some JS is being blocked there :/

Comment: @Oded just tried it in IE8 today and got no error. Nothing changed/updated on my end. I haven't even closed the browser/session.

Comment: To which all I can say... nothing changed on our end either. @phantom42

Comment: any change for you, @RobertF?

Comment: Woohoo, comment text box works fine for me today. No problems at home or on my iPhone, so must have been an issue with settings on my office desktop. Sometimes the default profile settings on our work computers will spontaneously reset if we power down at night & then log in again in the next morning.

Comment: @phantom42 [One of the possible causes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133033/internet-explorer-line-1-char-1-code-0-error) for that specific error message is if the URL in a script tag isn't returning javascript.  Did you happen to look at that URL while having the problem?  It could have been a temporary issue with that CDN, only affecting certain geographic areas...